# curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 189 when sending PUT request to Google Sheets API

Tags: rest, api, curl, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to write to a Google Spreadsheet using Google Sheet API v4. 
The usage about the API is listed [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing#write_a_single_range)

I made a `curl` request that looks like the following

```
curl -v\
-H 'Authorization: Bearer ya29.GlxSB9-EiDh1Mn2EqhCslHvkaGyOX-P4_yDR4MXOt-WdHYQdFfwUJNMfljAFzZfS-YrrATUU2MAKj3R4BcMyOSw55KjJOC0EekE_qusj8GXIxFF3uaGZxGMdlB0IlQ' \
-X PUT \
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1mHrPXQILuprO4NdqTgrVKlGazvvzgCFqIphGdsmptD8/values/Sheet1\!A1:D5\?valueInputOption\='{"range": "Sheet1!A1:D5","majorDimension": "ROWS","values": [["Item", "Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date"]
```

When I run this, I get the following error

```
curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 189
```

I do not understand what I am doing wrong and appreciate any help here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out, my use of API was incorrect. The right use of API is

```
curl -v \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer ya29.GlxSB9-EiDh1Mn2EqhCslHvkaGyOX-P4_yDR4MXOt-WdHYQdFfwUJNMfljAFzZfS-YrrATUU2MAKj3R4BcMyOSw55KjJOC0EekE_qusj8GXIxFF3uaGZxGMdlB0IlQ' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-X PUT \
-d '{"range": "Sheet1!A1:D5","majorDimension": "ROWS","values": [["Item", "Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date"], ["Wheel", "$20.50", "4", "3/1/2016"], ["Door", "$15", "2", "3/15/2016"], ["Engine", "$100", "1", "30/20/2016"], ["Totals", "=SUM(B2:B4)", "=SUM(C2:C4)", "=MAX(D2:D4)"]]}' \
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1mHrPXQILuprO4NdqTgrVKlGazvvzgCFqIphGdsmptD8/values/Sheet1!A1:D5?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED
```

The important points to note are
- `valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED`. I had to tell the API to parse the input so `USER_ENTERED` was a valid value as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing)
- The use of `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'` was needed since the payload was a valid `json` content.
- Sending the payload using `-d` option.

Once corrected, I was able to hit the API and get the response

```
*   Trying 2607:f8b0:400a:803::200a...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to sheets.googleapis.com (2607:f8b0:400a:803::200a) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google LLC; CN=*.googleapis.com
*  start date: Jul  2 19:21:00 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 24 18:57:00 2019 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "sheets.googleapis.com" matched cert's "*.googleapis.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services; CN=Google Internet Authority G3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x7fc02e006600)
> PUT /v4/spreadsheets/1mHrPXQILuprO4NdqTgrVKlGazvvzgCFqIphGdsmptD8/values/Sheet1!A1:D5?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED HTTP/2
> Host: sheets.googleapis.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer ya29.GlxSB9-EiDh1Mn2EqhCslHvkaGyOX-P4_yDR4MXOt-WdHYQdFfwUJNMfljAFzZfS-YrrATUU2MAKj3R4BcMyOSw55KjJOC0EekE_qusj8GXIxFF3uaGZxGMdlB0IlQ
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 272
>
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/2 200
< content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< vary: X-Origin
< vary: Referer
< vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
< date: Sat, 27 Jul 2019 19:23:15 GMT
< server: ESF
< cache-control: private
< x-xss-protection: 0
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43,39"
< accept-ranges: none
<
{
  "spreadsheetId": "1mHrPXQILuprO4NdqTgrVKlGazvvzgCFqIphGdsmptD8",
  "updatedRange": "Sheet1!A1:D5",
  "updatedRows": 5,
  "updatedColumns": 4,
  "updatedCells": 20
}
* Connection #0 to host sheets.googleapis.com left intact
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the following error

```
curl: (3) nested brace in URL position 8:
```

{findAllTransactionFile {id fileName}}}'

Well, that's probably the same as your server message "POST body sent invalid JSON.", right?

Now, when you fix your json data by using double-quotes on the outside and escaping the inner double-quotes, then it should work:

```
curl -v -d "{\"query\": \"{findAllTransactionFile {id fileName}}\"}" -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8080/apis/graphql
```

Comment: *   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /apis/graphql HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:application/json
> Content-Length: 51
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200
< Vary: Origin
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Mon, 18 Apr 2022 10:46:17 GMT

Answer (score 0):

If you have query parameters with braces, you can use this format:

```
curl -X PUT \
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1mHrPXQILuprO4NdqTgrVKlGazvvzgCFqIphGdsmptD8/values/Sheet1\!A1:D5\ \
 --data-urlencode '{"range": "Sheet1!A1:D5","majorDimension": "ROWS","values": [["Item", "Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date"], ["Wheel", "$20.50", "4", "3/1/2016"], ["Door", "$15", "2", "3/15/2016"], ["Engine", "$100", "1", "30/20/2016"], ["Totals", "=SUM(B2:B4)", "=SUM(C2:C4)", "=MAX(D2:D4)"]]}'
```

Where `--data-urlencode` tells curl to encode the URL, so that there won't be any nested braces