# How to add headers in the curl request example of the postman API document

Tags: api, curl, postman, postman-collection-runner, api-doc

How to add a given header to an api request example in the postman api document.
I am using 'Content-Type': 'application/json'  in the headers of postman to test my api  requests.  However, after generating the postman document from my api collection the curl request example was:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://domain/endpoint' \
--data-raw '{"key1": "value1",
"key2": value2}'
```

I want to add --header 'Content-Type: application/json' to the curl request example in the doc.
The request should be:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://domain/endpoint' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"key1": "value1",
"key2": value2}'
```

I found in this link that it is possible:
https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-team-collections/documentation/1372588-81512aa8-f91a-4bcd-a53a-6037780c730e
See the picture from the doc:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOTW2.png)

I tried many possible options from pre script to collection general headers without results and it isn't possible to edit the curl request inside the doc after been generated.

Comment: https://learning.postman.com/docs/publishing-your-api/authoring-your-documentation/#using-examples-in-your-docs
Even in the official doc the subject wasn't evoked

Comment: `--request POST` should also be removed when `--data-raw` is used. Especially in combination with `--location`...

Comment: Yes it can be but it works with. The biggest issue still the missing headers in the curl request

Comment: It only works with it when you're lucky: https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2015/09/11/unnecessary-use-of-curl-x/

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurred because I didn't really manually set the content-type header in postman.
The header that I see in Content-Type was in the hidden section of the postman headers so automatically set by postman.

Answer (score 0):

When using `curl` for testing your API, Postman does not help a lot in generating your headers as you said above, but you can still build your own command simply by using different options provided by `curl`, example:

```
curl -v \
-H 'myToken: ...Bpq7gwLMBm_WqWdusSiNKI9pVNU9BTtsOerp14920IFktpcyvK...' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-X POST \
-d '{"key1": "value1", "key2": value2}' \
http://domain/endpoint
```

Please note to

1. use `-H` option for adding each of your headers
2. if your payload has a `json` format, please add the correspondent *content-type*.
3. use `-X` to indicate the type of your Http request
4. use `-d` to add your payload

I had some similar problems when using Postman-generated `curl` commands, and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57235170/curl-3-globbing-nested-brace-in-column-189-when-sending-put-request-to-goog) helped me build my own.

Hope this could still help people stuck in similar problems.